# Change size of cursor in TextField (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, textfield, android-jetpack-compose

I want to decrease the 'height' of cursor in my TextField. How do I do that?

My TextField with default cursor height looks like:

[image: My TextField]

Comment: try reducing the `fontSize` , also u can tinker with height and styles

Answer (score 1):

We can custom the text field cursor via `CoreTextField.cursorBrush`, with `Brush.verticalGradient` and `colorStops` argument.

```
BasicTextField(
    cursorBrush = Brush.verticalGradient(
        0.00f to Color.Transparent,
        0.35f to Color.Transparent,
        0.35f to Color.Green,
        0.90f to Color.Green,
        0.90f to Color.Transparent,
        1.00f to Color.Transparent
    )
)
```