# How can I change the size (height) of the cursor of a TextField in jetpack compose irrespective of font size?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

How can I change the size of the cursor (height) of a TextField in jetpack compose irrespective of font size ? any tips or tricks ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68860541

By playing with the gradient, you can make the colors Transparent on the ends of the cursor. I cannot make this work in Material 3 though...

```
BasicTextField(
    cursorBrush = Brush.verticalGradient(
        0.00f to Color.Transparent,
        0.35f to Color.Transparent,
        0.35f to Color.Green,
        0.90f to Color.Green,
        0.90f to Color.Transparent,
        1.00f to Color.Transparent
    )
)
```

Comment: does that work with TextField ?

Comment: No it seems like cursorBrush exists only in some TextField variants, but not all. Sorry.